# How to serve up a base64 string as image?

Tags: node.js, base64

I have a base64 string from the database that I want to serve up via GET. I know that is has to be converted first to buffer and then I need to set the Content-Type to image/png (since my image is a png). The problem is the image is not showing up. If it helps, I'm using Nest JS as framework.

This is the base64 string that I am trying to serve up:
https://pastebin.com/kbvGLXSp

I've tried running the endpoint via Chrome and Postman, I get the same results. The image is not showing up

```
// From auth.controller.ts
@Get('avatar')
@Header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
  async getAvatar(){
    return await this.authServ.getAvatar();
  }


// From auth.service.ts
async getAvatar() {
    const db = this.AUTH_REPOSITORY;
    const user = await db.findOne({where: {id: 1}});
    return Buffer.from(user.avatar, 'base64');
}
```

The image should be showing up but its not. I get something like this in chrome: (https://i.ibb.co/kMWJxn2/Capture.png)

Comment: Are you trying to serve the image as a Base64 encoded entity, or just the plain binary entity?

Comment: @haraldK It turns out the error was with the content type. express is automatically appending charset=utf-8 which is the reason why the image is not showing up. Found a way to remove it from the header and it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For reference:**

*Problem:* Content-Type was showing `image/png; charset=utf-8` when it should just be `image/png`

*Solution:* Use writehead and end

```
const buffer = await this.authServ.getavatar();
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});   
res.end(buffer);
```